# XML/XSD Restriction

Tags: xml, xsd

can someone help me please with a restriction.I have an element called `name`, and this one should not begin with `-` but can contains a `-`.I don´t know how to do it that it cannot beginn with `-`

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you are familiar with the concept of [regular expresions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).
If yes, then should be easy for you to [apply a regular expression inside an XSD file](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html).

Comment: I assume that you have an XSD file, correct? If you follow the second link a shared with you, you will see how you can define regex inside xsd restrictions. Can you put there this regex (inside double quotes) and tell me what is happening? regex is "[^-].*" which means I want my first character be whatever except - and then I dont care

Comment: by the way, I just tried that and it worked. You need also to escape the character. The valid regex is  <xs:pattern value="[^\-].*"/>

Comment: i have this one: <xs:pattern value="([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9ä,ö,ü,Ä,Ö,Ü,ß]*[ |-]?)*[^-].*"/>

Comment: Those commas within the square brackets are wrong. All they do is to allow a comma to appear within a name - probably not what you intended.

Comment: Incidentally, is this really what you want to do? My grandmother was German and her surname was Darré. Is there any good reason you would not want her in your database? Integrity rules that restrict your data should only be there if either (a) the data definitely can't occur in the real world, or (b) it can occur but your application can't cope with it.